# Sending out a media-url served on a static server in django

Tags: django

I have a flash file which is on a separate media server and the relative path is

```
/flash/as3.swf
```

I want to pass this to the template so when it gets rendered it gives the absolute path i.e.

```
http://myweb.site.com/flash/as3.swf
```

but when I render it the url is always `/flash/as3.swf`

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you trying to pass it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard MEDIA_URL setting in your django settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://myweb.site.com/'
```

Then in template, use

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}flash/as3.swf
```

MEDIA_URL will be available in your templates if you render them with RequestContext instance